# Declaring dynamic prototype methods to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm converting a javascript class with several "generated" prototype methods to typescript. The generated methods are mapped to an internal object so the API is cleaner/more convenient for 80% of its use cases.

However, I'm find no way to properly tell typescript which methods exist without actually implementing them.

```
class A {}

A.prototype.test = function() {}

var a = new A().test();
```

It errors with `error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'A'`

It seems like I can get around it by defining the property manually, but that hinders the usefulness of automatically mapping these methods.

```
class A {
    test: any;
}

A.prototype.test = function() {}

var a = new A();
a.test();
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with typescript (yet) but shouldn't you be doing something like this: class A {}

A.prototype.test = function() {console.log('test');}

var a = new A();

a.test();

Comment: It would be better practice to wrap the new A() with parenthesis but for the purposes of this demo it doesn't have any impact.

Comment: Right. but when you instantiate `A` as a new class, `.test()` isn't accessible yet. There for you have to do `var a = new A();` then you can access `a.test()` ...I may be misunderstanding the issue, however.

Comment: I do not see a possibility of achieving this in TypeScript, compiler won't allow you to do that. Because TypeScript internally while generating the JS code puts all the methods and properties of a class on the prototype chain of a function having same name of the class.

Comment: I'm also doing what you propose i.e declaring attribute with type like `test: any;` on one of my project. It works pretty well but I don't find this very elegant. Maybe generating `.d.ts` file would be better, but it really depends on the use case you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I'm find no way to properly tell typescript which methods exist without actually implementing them.

If the methods are generated why even define the class? i.e. instead of `class A` you really should only be *declaring the class* i.e. you should be doing:

```
declare class A {
  test();
}
```

Comment: `why even define the class?` Maybe the class doesn't contain only dynamic stuff. ;)

Comment: @Blackus The implementation can be generated with full or partial dynamic stuff. The class can be declared in both of the cases.

Comment: @Paleo Yeah but I mean, if there are some methods on class `A` that are defined on it, not just "attached", `declare` isn't enough, right?

Comment: @Blackus The declaration and the implementation must be in distinct files. I just wrote another answer to explain.

Comment: The class contains plenty of methods/properties which are not generated, so I'd still need to use `class A`.

Answer (score 0):

> I can get around it by defining the property manually

Yes. Because of the dynamic part, the type cannot be statically inferred by TypeScript. It has to be manually defined:

```
class A {
    test: () => void;
}
A.prototype.test = function() {}
```

Or, another way that I use sometimes:

1. Dynamically build the API in TypeScript module files, that export some members;
2. Compile to JavaScript code;
3. Write a file `index.d.ts` that *declares* the exported module members of the API (like the answer of @basarat);
4. In a separated project (with another `tsconfig.json`), import the module members of the API, from the JavaScript code, with the help of the declarations in `index.d.ts`.

This process is particularly suited to publish a *npm* package.

Comment: For my specific needs this is probably overkill, unfortunately. Part of the reason they were generated was to automatically update one with new methods from what was being mapped - it seems that in every solution I'd have to manage an actual static list somewhere. I'd rather write a wrapper function for those that are more than one line and just implement them in the api - it also solves a problem I had being unable to js-doc the generated methods as well.